# Running subprocess.call with pytest fails in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions

I have a CI pipeline in GitHub.

In a `test.py` file, I have the following:

```py
subprocess.call(
    args=[
        "python",
        "./folder/file.py",
        "--file_path",
        "tests/local_tests/test_data/data.txt",  # pylint: disable=line-too-long
        "--silent",
    ]
)
```

Running it with `pytest` gives:

```
----------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./folder/file.py", line 10, in <module>
    from folder.aux import function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder'
```

Which in turn makes the test to fail with another exception.
When I run locally the test, everything goes smoothly.

Edit:

```
name: integration_tests_container
run-name: ${{ github.actor }}'s integration tests on ES container
on:
    pull_request:
        branches: [main, dev]
        types: [opened, reopened]
    push:
        paths-ignore:
            - '**.md'
            - './docs'
            - 'Dockerfile'
            - './.github/workflows/ci-production.yml'
            - './.github/workflows/evaluate_clustering.yml'
            - './.github/workflows/build_docs.yml'
jobs:
    run_integration_tests:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        strategy:
            matrix:
                python-version: [3.8]
        steps:
            - name: Setup Python
              uses: actions/setup-python@v4
              with:
                python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
                
            - name: Checkout branch
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Install requirements
              run: |
                pip install -r requirements.txt

            - name: Launching ES db container
              run: |
                cd ./folder_local_db
                docker compose up -d

            - name: Execute tests
              run: |
                sleep 20 # to avoid connection error
                python -m pytest ./tests/integration_tests
```

Comment: Please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Looks like a relative path import issue. Did you try to verify the paths where that `folder` is located? Are those exactly the same steps that work locally for you?